# Nested class include header

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that looks like this:

```
// List.hpp
template<typename T>
class List {
    ...
private:
    class Node;
};
```

And I want to put the full definition of `List<T>::Node` into a separate file:

```
// Node.hpp
template<typename T>
class List<T>::Node {
    ...
};
```

My question is, what should I include in each file, and where to put the `#include`s?

The simplest method (I think) is to include `Node.hpp` at the end of `List.hpp`, and not include anything in `Node.hpp`. However, this makes `Node.hpp` on its own not a complete file (say if I open it in an IDE or something there would be a lot of errors due to missing the definition of `List<T>`). Also, I'm not sure if it's okay to put `#include`s at the bottom of a file.

Assuming each file has its own include guard `#define`, I can also include `List.hpp` at the top of `Node.hpp` (to make IDEs happy), and then include `Node.hpp` at the bottom of `List.hpp` again, but I don't know if that's a good idea.

Comment: Adressing parts of your question: You can put an `#incldue` anywhere you want and I don't see, how it would help you, if you include the same file twice.

Comment: You can do what you suggest -- you could also selectively include it in other .h or .cpp files as needed.  This can reduce the compilation blast radius of changing node.hpp to only the places that actually use it, instead of everything that includes list.hpp

Comment: also, here's a live example of this arrangement working: https://godbolt.org/g/5c4HC7

Comment: semi-offtopic: If I have a lot of templated code in a .h file that's getting changed a lot, I'll often move it from filename.h to filename_impl.h and then only include it in the .cpp files that actually use that templated method.  It stops a large portion of the project from detecting the change and rebuilding when they only needed the type info, not the implementation details.  If you miss a spot, the compiler gives a pretty good link error telling you were to include the _impl.

Comment: @MikeMB *...if you include the same file twice.* Having `Node.hpp` include `List.hpp` at its top makes `Node.hpp` on its own a complete compilation unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When compiling member functions of `List<T>::Node`, the compiler will always need visibility of the templated class `List`.   A consequence of this is that any compilation unit which needs visibility of the contents of `Node.hpp` will need visibility of the contents (definition of the templated members) of `List.hpp`.

The simplest option is placing the contents of `Node.hpp` at the end of `List.hpp`, and only `#include "List.h"` in compilation units that need either template.   That eliminates the need for `Node.hpp` completely.

If you really must have both headers (which seems arbitrary and pointless to me, as `List<T>::Node` is a component of `List<T>`) an option is to help with include guards.

```
  // List.hpp

  #ifndef LIST_HPP_INCLUDED   // some unique macro
  #define LIST_HPP_INCLUDED

  // definition of templated class List

  #include "Node.hpp"   // this must be after the definition of List<T>
  #endif
```

and in Node.hpp

```
  // Node.hpp

  #ifndef NODE_HPP_INCLUDED   // some unique macro
  #define NODE_HPP_INCLUDED

  #include "List.hpp"     // this must precede the definitions for List<T>::Node

  // definition of templated class List<T>::Node

  #endif
```

This allows either header to be `#include`d by any compilation units, and the include guards stop infinitely recursive includes.

Most modern IDEs do cope with this.  If you have one that doesn't, then simply transition to a single header file.

Comment: I wanted to separate `Node` to its own file just to make `List.hpp` cleaner, but as you say it's not necessary.

Comment: Also, if I do as you suggest (putting `class List<T>::Node { ... }` at the end of `List.hpp`), can't I just as well define `Node` inside `List` directly?

Comment: Well, yes.   `Node` is a nested class of `List<T>`.      The definition of any nested class - templated or not - can be placed within the definition of the containing class.